# Is it possible to create a react native sdk, that only works on android with native code?

Tags: android, react-native

I would like to create an sdk for react native apps to use for android, and the sdk should use native code as it will be talking to android system services.

Does anyone know how this is achievable/ is there a guide somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a thing they called Native Modules, it's available for Android & for IOS. Please take a look at the official documentation : https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android  https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios